# Replacing diagonal elements with another array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices, `A` and `P`. I would like to replace the diagonal elements of `A` with the elements of `P`. The desired  output is attached.

```
A=np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0]])

P=np.array([[3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[3, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 4, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 5, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fill_diagonal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) with the flattened P as values for the diagonal:

```
np.fill_diagonal(A, P.ravel())
```

*NB. the operation is in place*

output:

```
array([[3, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 4, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 5, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 6]])
```

Comment: This works but I want to use a new variable and keep the original matrix, ```A```.

Comment: @Wiz123 then make a copy ;) `B = A.copy() ; np.fill_diagonal(B, P.ravel())`